# Can't execute NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL in Swift

Tags: ios, json, swift

I have a code to get an employee data from php returned Json which is the following :

```
[{"id":"1","email":"KK","password":"KKK","firstName":"KKK","lastName":"KK","photo":null,"phone":"22","mobile":"2","position":"SS","adminstrator_id":"1","department_id":"1"}]
```

**Code I have try:**

```
func getEmpById (id:String) {
    emp = employee()

    let myUrl = NSURL(string:"http://localhost/On%20Call%20App/scripts/getEmployee.php?id=\(id)")

    let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()

    let task = session.dataTaskWithURL(myUrl!, completionHandler: {
        (data, response, error) -> Void in

        do {
            let json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: .MutableContainers) as! [[String: AnyObject]]
            let dic = json[0]


            if let  id = dic["id"] , firstName = dic["firstName"] ,lastName = dic["lastName"], mobile = dic["mobile"],phone = dic["phone"],email=dic["email"],pos=dic["position"]{



                self.emp.setId(id as! String )

                self.emp.setFirstName(firstName as! String)

                self.emp.setLastName(lastName as! String)

                self.emp.setPhone(phone as! String)

                self.emp.setMobile(mobile as! String)

                self.emp.setEmail(email as! String)

                self.emp.setPosition(pos as! String)



            }


        } catch {
            print(error)

        }

    })
    task.resume()


}
```

The problem in this line `let task = session.dataTaskWithURL(myUrl!, completionHandler:{` when the app reach this line it will directly go to `task.resume()` without printing any error

Any help to make this work ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your response is of `Array` type not `Dictionary`

```
 let json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: .MutableContainers) as! NSArray
 let dic = json[0] as! NSDictionary
 print(dic.objectForKey("email"))
```

It is batter if use use Swift array like this.

```
 let json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: .MutableContainers) as! [[String: AnyObject]]
 let dic = json[0]
 print(dic["email"])
```

Comment: ok thanks but my problem is the app get out when reaching this line let task = session.dataTaskWithURL ,

Comment: Api is execute in background change your code like my and put the print statement you will get output in console.

Comment: Thank you . finally it works , but can you explain to me how the executoin work here ? when I debug the code never enter but I get the print(dic["email"]) on the console